# Enforce datatypes passed to methods (Option Strict)

Tags: .net, vb.net, option-strict

I am using VS2005 to maintain some vb.net code.  I am preparing to update to newer toolsets and am doing code cleanup first.

I am cleaning up all the compile error messages, but I noticed that I do not get a warning if I pass a String to a function that is expecting an Integer.

How can I force that warning?

The specific situation is that I am changing this code:

```
Public Function MyFunc(ByVal MyVar)
```

to

```
Public Function MyFunc(ByVal MyVar As Integer)
```

And I want to find all the places that were NOT passing in an Integer.

Comment: Turning `Option Strict On` in the project properties "Compile" tab should flag those.

Comment: I don't see anything like that; perhaps that is on newer versions of VS?

Comment: Just type `Option Strict On` to the top of each code file until you figure out project settings

Comment: That is even better because I can deal with this mess one file at a time.  make that an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Selectively Turn on `Option Strict`

Add to the top of the code file:

```
Option Strict On
```

Since this will enforce the option only in those files, this method is not recommended on an ongoing basis because it requires you to remember to do so for each file.

#### Project Wide

Open **Project Properties** (**Project** Menu - **Properties** among others).  On the **Compile** Tab set the `Option Strict` drop down to **On**.  You can also demote some conditions from an error to a warning or ignore that condition.

This too can be forgotten.

### Visual Studio Default (recommended)

You can make `Option Strict On` the default setting for all new projects, so you don't have to remember to do so at any level:

**Tools** Menu -> **Projects and Solutions** -> **VB Defaults**

This wont affect a project already in the works - use #2 for that.