# Saving over existing file loop VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a picturebox that captures screenshots and saves them in a certain directory. 
The code works in such a way that the screenshot name contains the value of the number of screenshots taken e.g. the 3rd screenshot = "screenshot3" or the 5th screenshot = "screenshot5". 
Label3.Text represents the number of screenshots taken which is saved in the name of my bmp image file.

This is the following code :

```
  PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
  Label3.Text = Val(Label3.Text) + 1
  PictureBox2.Image.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDire​ctories.AllUsersApplicationData, "screenshot" & Label3.Text & ".bmp"))
  PictureBox2.Image = Nothing
```

**What I wanted to do** was that when the 5th screenshot is captured, the value of Label3.Text goes back to 1 and the new screenshots that are taken overwrite the existing .bmp files back up to the 5th screenshot.

I tried to solve this by creating a timer that would reset the Label3.Text value back to 1 when the 5th screenshot was taken:

```
Private Sub Timer6_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer6.Tick
If Label3.Text = 5 Then
        Label3.Text = Val(Label3.Text) - 4
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I received the message problem : **"External Exception was unhandled. A generic error occurred in GDI+."**

Hopefully someone can help me here :)

Comment: Why do you need a timer to check if the count is 5?  You should turn on `Option Strict`, read [ask] and take the [tour].  Your app is also leaking.

Comment: What is Option Strict? What do you mean when you said my app is leaking?

Comment: [Enabling Option Strict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531217/1070452).  There are zillions of posts here on the generic GDI error and please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I'm new to vb.net. It would help if you could explain it to me and tell me how it's related to my problem... I turned on Option Strict and I'm still receiving the same error message...

Comment: Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance to all comments!

Comment: This has taken ages :( Thanks again to anyone that helps