# Exception Handling Issues

Tags: vb.net, exception

I'm having some difficulties with exception handling. I'm fairly new to programming, but I'm currently writing some code that p your age as of August 10, as well as some fun facts about the decade you were born, when you input your date of birth. Whenever I try to debug, it says I need to do some exception handling, and I don't know what that is. Any help? My code is below.

```
Public Class Form1 'this program will tell people their age as of 8/10/2017 and will give them some fun facts about the decade they were born in.
Dim A As Integer = 2017 - TextBoxYear.Text
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    If 1920 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1929 Then 'this section is all about sending people the fun facts. Each part defines what decade they are in, and gives fun facts.
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 1920's! Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi began a sweeping non-violent reform movement in India in 1920, and on August 18, 1920, women won the right to vote.")
    End If 'every decade has a little personalized message like this.
    If 1930 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1939 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 1930's! World War II began in Europe in 1939 when Germany invades Poland, and the first supermarket opened in 1930.")
    End If
    If 1940 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1949 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 1940's! The end of World War II in Asia occurred on August 14/15, 1945, when Japan surrendered to the Allied Powers, and Velcro was invented in 1948 in Switzerland by George deMestral.")
    End If
    If 1950 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1959 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 1950's! Disneyland opened in 1955 and in Montgomery, Alabama, a bus boycott begins after Rosa Parks refuses to give up her seat to a white person.")
    End If
    If 1960 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1969 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 1960's! John F. Kennedy was assassinated in 1963 in Dallas, and on August 28, 1963, Martin Luther King, Jr. gave the powerful speech now commonly known as: I have a dream.")
    End If
    If 1970 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1979 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 1970's! Richard Nixon becomes the only President of the United States to ever resign from his position, and FeDex opened its doors in 1973.")
    End If
    If 1980 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1989 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 1980's! In 1980, John Lennon was assassinated in New York City. In 1981, Microsoft was asked to create an operating system for IBM computers.")
    End If
    If 1990 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1999 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 1990's! The 90s were a solid decade, with great movies like Pulp Fiction, great music like Radiohead and great cars like the Dodge Viper.")
    End If
    If 2000 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 2009 Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in the 2000's! The first humans born in the 21st century, you were born during the decade that Obama was elected president and the first iPhone was invented.")
    End If
    If 2010 <= TextBoxYear.Text Then
        Console.WriteLine("You were born in this decade, the 2010's! If you're even old enough to read this, you should know that this is the decade of the rise of personal techology, and that this is the decade Donald Trump was elected in.")
    End If
    'This section is about finding the age of people, on the date August 10, 2017. It's better explained in my flowchart, which is attached as an image in the assignment submission.
    If 8 > TextBoxMonth.Text Then
        Console.WriteLine(A, "is your age!")
    End If
    If 8 < TextBoxMonth.Text Then
        Console.WriteLine(A - 1, "is your age!")
    End If
    If 8 = TextBoxMonth.Text Then
        If TextBoxDay.Text <= 10 Then
            Console.WriteLine(A, "is your age!")
        End If
        If TextBoxDay.Text > 10 Then
            Console.WriteLine(A - 1, "is your age!")
        End If

    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried searching in Google first? anyway, have a look at this tutorial.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_exception_handling.htm

Comment: I don't think that code will throw any actual exceptions...however, I don't think it is going to behave like you intend it to either. The comparisons written like this "1970 <= TextBoxYear.Text <= 1979" are not going to work, and you will also get multiple incorrect outputs given any year. Also, add "Option Strict On" and "Option Explicit On" to your code, there are all kinds of unsafe comparisons going on between strings and inferred numbers...

Comment: Love it `'this program ... will give them some fun facts about the decade they were born in ... World War II began in Europe in 1939 when Germany invades Poland`

Comment: First, read [ask] and take the [tour].  Then set [Option Strict On](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531217/1070452), then read up on how the  [If Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement).works and the syntax for it.

Comment: _ it says I need to do some exception handling_ - What exactly does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would say that Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site, but I think you could benefit greatly from a few pointers.(You wrote a flow chart! Shows enthusiasm!)

I think that you meant to say that your code has errors, not exceptions. There are also a couple of style Issues I would like to show you. They are not big problems, but they will help you in the future.No worries though.

When you are writing something like

```
If 1920 <= TextBoxYear.Text
```

It is the most common practice to put the object/variable being compared first and what it is being compared to second, so you would write ..

```
If TextBoxYear.Text >=1920
```

Which brings me to my next point. Your original `If..Then` statements would not compile as other commenters have mentioned. For them to work, you would have to write something like ..

```
If TextBoxYear.Text >= 1920 Or TextBoxYear.Text <= 1929 Then
```

Visual Basic can't compare one object to two others in the way you thought.

Next time you write code with a lot of `If..Then` statements that are comparing the same object, you might be much better using `Select..Case..End Select` One of the beauties of this code is that it is neat end easy to read 6 months later when you have to maintain it.

Your last piece of code to calculate age can be done more efficiently - like this -

```
Dim dob As Date = New Date(CInt(TextBoxYear.Text), CInt(TextBoxMonth.Text), CInt(TextBoxDay.Text))
A = 2017 - dob.Year
If (dob > #2017/08/10#.AddYears(-A)) Then
    A -= 1
End If
Console.WriteLine(A & " is your age!")
```

But, as you have already written a flow chart, you might want to leave that code alone.

OK Last two things.

You may notice that I have added a lot of `CInt(` functions to your code. The reason is that TextBoxYear.Text actually returns a string - even if there are only numbers. By default, Visual Studio will try it's best to convert a string to the type you want. In your case, an Integer. However, writing code like this can lead to lots of problems with more complex code. To fight this, you can change one of the options in Visual Studio. It's called Option Strict. If you turn this on, it means that you are responsible for making all the conversions between two different types, like from string to integer or double to integer. It makes you write more code, but there will be less problems to find later.

Option Strict is Off By Default. To switch it on click on these ..

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB defaults -> Option Strict. Set it to On.

Finally! In your WriteLine statements, you wrote ..

```
A, "is your age!"
```

this won't work at all. Console.WriteLine expects a single string as the parameter in this case. To make your output into a single string, you need to use the concatenation operator `&` .. like this

```
A.ToString & " is your age!"
```

As far as `Console.WriteLine` is concerned, this is just one string. Magic!

The `.ToString' is one of the ways to convert an object (in this case an integer) to a string.

I hope this helps, and keep practicing!