# Programming a game loop for single player Blackjack

Tags: vb.net, blackjack

I've been working on a game of blackjack on visual basic but have been stuck on a particular task which states:

"Create a game loop to play a one-player version of the game. The game should end with the player going bust or holding on a valid score under 22."

I have gotten to code working up until that point with subroutines that manage "shuffling" the stack of figurative cards, dealing a card, checking if the player has busted or not and one that processes the player's turn.

(The commented out section is my attempt at the game loop, it does not work as once i input S or T it carries on asking if i want to stick or twist over and over)
Here is my full code:

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    'task 1
    Dim deck() As String = {"AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", 
    "9H", "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH",
    "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD",
    "AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS",
    "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC"}
    Dim hand As New List(Of String)

    Dim cardPile As New Stack(Of String)
    cardPile = Shuffle(deck)

    Dealing(cardPile, hand)
    Dealing(cardPile, hand)

    Dim BustOrNot As String
    BustOrNot = Left(Bust(hand), 2)
    Dim total As Integer
    total = Mid(Bust(hand), 3, Bust(hand).Length)
    If total = 21 Then
        BlackJack(total)
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("Your total so far is: " & total)

    'Dim stickOrTwist As Boolean
    'stickOrTwist = PlayerTurn(hand)

    'While BustOrNot = "NB" Or stickOrTwist = False Or total = 21
    'Dealing(cardPile, hand)
    'BustOrNot = Left(Bust(hand), 2)
    'stickOrTwist = PlayerTurn(hand)
    'End While
    'If stickOrTwist = False Then
    'Win(total)
    'ElseIf BustOrNot = "BB" Then
    'Lose(total)
    'ElseIf total = 21 Then
    'BlackJack(total)
    'End If
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
Function Shuffle(ByVal deck As Array)
    'task 2
    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim card As String
    Dim card2 As String
    Dim indexToShuffle As Integer
    Dim indexToShuffle2 As Integer
    Dim cardStack As New Stack(Of String)

    For i = 1 To 1000
        indexToShuffle = rand.Next(0, 51)
        card = deck(indexToShuffle)
        indexToShuffle2 = rand.Next(0, 51)
        card2 = deck(indexToShuffle2)

        deck(indexToShuffle2) = card
        deck(indexToShuffle) = card2
    Next

    For j = 0 To 51
        cardStack.Push(deck(j))
    Next

    Return cardStack
End Function
Sub Dealing(ByRef cardPile As Stack(Of String), hand As List(Of String))
    'task 3
    hand.Add(cardPile.Pop)
End Sub
Function Bust(ByVal hand As List(Of String))
    'task 4
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    For Each item In hand
        If IsNumeric(Left(item, 1)) Then
            total = total + Left(item, 1)
        ElseIf Left(item, 1) = "A" Then
            total = total + 11
        ElseIf Left(item, 1) = "J" Or Left(item, 1) = "Q" Or Left(item, 1) = "K" Then
            total = total + 10
        End If
    Next

    If total > 21 Then
        Return ("BB" & total)
    Else
        Return ("NB" & total)
    End If

End Function
Function PlayerTurn(ByRef hand As List(Of String))
    'task 5
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to stick or twist? (Input S or T)")
    Dim stickOrTwist As String = UCase(Console.ReadLine())

    If stickOrTwist = "S" Then
        Return False
    ElseIf stickOrTwist = "T" Then
        Return True
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("That isn't a valid input. Try again")
        Console.WriteLine("...")
        PlayerTurn(hand)
    End If
End Function
Sub Lose(ByVal total As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("Oh no! you lose.")
    Console.WriteLine("Your final score was: " & total)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
Sub Win(ByVal total As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("Well done! your score is: " & total)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
Sub BlackJack(ByVal total As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("Well done you scored blackjack! Your score is: " & total)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: is this a console app?  Is it just dealing cards or does the player decide to hit?  That is not a proper shuffle and you should set `Option Strict On`

Comment: yeah its a console app and basically all the loop is supposed to do is ask if the player wants to stick or twist; if they want to twist it should deal another card, check if they've gone bust, let them know what their new total is and then ask again if they wanna stick or twist until they either go bust or decide to stick. Not gonna lie i also don't know what Option Strict On is haha

Comment: You just need a Do loop like `Do Until Busted OrElse PlayerStands` use booleans, not secret codes like "BB", "NB".  One handed seems...odd since the dealer could win.  **[Option Strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529281/enforce-datatypes-passed-to-methods-option-strict/43531217#43531217)**

Comment: Your Bust function could be called HandTotal and just return the total.  Also, it won't work for 10.  It counts the card as 1.

Comment: `If IsNumeric(Left(item, 1)) Then` `total = total + Left(item, 1)` fails when card is 10

Comment: ...Also Aces can be 1 *or* 11 - you need to score it both ways and pick the best

Comment: @Plutonix `One handed seems...odd since the dealer could win` I'd imagine that will be the next homework assignment.

Comment: i changed the bust function and fixed it so the 10 can be counted, but I was told to count all aces as 11, just for simplicity as I am not very advanced in my coding yet.

Comment: The next assignment *should be* to rework it using classes to elide all that Mid Trim Val junk code.  @djv

Comment: Just a small detail. Random.Next(Int32, Int32) returns an Integer but reading the fine print you find out that the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive. This means in your shuffle code you will never get an index of 51.